# CakePHP custom validation - check for specific number of uppercase, symbols and numbers

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

As title says, I need to validate password field but it can contains specific number of uppercase letters, special characters and numbers. So I created function like this

```
function password_verification($password){
$errors[];
$min_password_length = ConfigOptions::getValue('password_minimum_length');// minimum password length
$special_characters = ConfigOptions::getValue('password_minimum_symbols');// Minimum symbols
$numbers = ConfigOptions::getValue('password_minimum_numbers');// minimum numbers
$length = strlen($password);// length of inserted password
preg_match_all("/[A-Z]/", $password, $caps_match);
$caps_count = count($caps_match [0]);// number of uppercase letters in password
preg_match_all("/[a-z]/", $password, $small_match);
$small_count = count($small_match [0]);// number of lowercase letters in password
preg_match_all("/[0-9]/", $password, $num_match);
$num_count = count($num_match [0]);// number of digits in password
preg_match_all("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", $password, $symb_match);
$symb_count = count($symb_match [0]);
if($min_password_length > $length) {
    $errors['password_length'] = __('Password cannot be shorter than '.$min_password_length.' characters');
}// if
if($uppercase > $caps_count) {
    $errors['password_uppercase'] = __('Password cannot have less than '.$uppercase.' uppercase letters');
}// if
if($special_characters > $symb_count) {
    $errors[] = __('Password cannot have less than '.$symb_count.' special characters');
}// if
if($numbers > $num_count) {
    $errors[] = __('Paswword cannot have less than '.$num_count.' numbers');
}// if
return $errors[];
}
```

and I put this in controller. But I was wondering is there any way to put this in model validation.

Comment: Indeed, take a look at: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#custom-validation-rules

Comment: I really can't bother to answer did I look at cakebook...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a validation rule for each of your conditions. here is a general idea of what you need to put in your model:

```
public $validate = array(
    'password' => array(
            'id_rule_1' => array(
                'rule' => 'isPasswordGreaterThanMinLenght'
            ),
            'id_rule_2' => array(
                'rule' => 'isCapsCountLimitReached'
            ),
        ));


public function isPasswordGreaterThanMinLenght($check){
    $min_password_length = ConfigOptions::getValue('password_minimum_length');// minimum password length
    $length = strlen($this->data['password']);// length of inserted password
    $this->validator()->getField('password')->getRule('id_rule_1')->message = 'Password cannot be shorter than '.$min_password_length.' characters';
    return ($min_password_length > $length);
}

public function isCapsCountLimitReached($check){
    $uppercase = '';//define uppercase here
    $password = $this->data['password'];
    preg_match_all("/[A-Z]/", $password, $caps_match);
    $caps_count = count($caps_match [0]);// number of uppercase letters in password
    $this->validator()->getField('password')->getRule('id_rule_2')->message = 'Password cannot have less than '.$uppercase.' uppercase letters';
    return ($uppercase > $caps_count);
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I know how to do this, but I also need to check is there a minimum number of digits and symbols.